# Netbeans 8 Java creating new entities classes from database - no primary key

Tags: jpa, netbeans, pervasive

I'm using netbeans 8 on Win7 64 to connect to a pervasive db (db of which I'm not the admin).

I'm running into errors when trying to generate the JPA layer through the entity classes from the database, for each table it renders: 'no primary key'. The driver is the JDBC connector from pervasive itself.

As far as I could research and understand, the problem is with non matching primary key names (both in name and case). Since I can't change that, is there another workaround? Since there's a 100+ tables with on average 30 columns, I really don't see it achievable to do this manually ...

Help is very much appreciated!!

Comment: Did you figure this out or did you manually create them?

Comment: I created them manually (just one table for testing) - I'd still be interested in the solution ...